# Uploading files gives ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, file-upload, swfupload

When uploading files that are larger and take longer I get this response:

First time I try to upload a big file it seem to get: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
after that it becomes ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I checked all the upload limits etc all are 240seconds or higher and 256mb
I tried uploading 200mb file. 
It always seems to happen at the same moment which is at 1 min.

There are no 60 second limits or anything in the phpinfo.
Also tried locally upping all the limits with no result.

Here is the main upload part. If additional info required I'll update the question A.S.A.P

Edit: Just came across this which is being used as well: SWFUpload
Getting error code 2038
Reinstalling flash doesn't work, neither do other browsers!

Answer (score 1):

increase upload_max_filesize, max_input_time, and post_max_size an memory_limit in your php.ini. eventhought 200MB it is too big. if it is text/csv you might want to split the file in multiple files.